# What changes need to be made in makefile to enable display report of auto vectorization?

Tags: c++, vectorization

Compilation and execution of the program are correct but I couldn't get the report on vectorization done by the compiler even though I have used `-fopt-info-vec-optimized` flag.

`patterngenerator` is the c++ file name and `pattern` is the object

Contents of the makefile are as follows:

```
OBJ = pattern 

pattern: patterngenerator.cc 
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/c++ -D_SYSTYPE_SYSV -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD \
-DCHOLMOD_USES_MKL -DD1_PORT -DDRC_LOCAL -DQT_NO_KEYWORDS -D_REENTRANT \
-D_THREAD_SAFE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 \
-fcheck-new -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-deprecated -Werror -DUSES_CLP_CODE \
-DNPIX_CALIBRE_CODE -DENABLE_CMP -DMKL_SOLVER -DXCAL_DEV -DXCALIBREH_BUILD \
-DPEXVIEWQT -DTHREADED -DLVS_RVE -DUSES_CLP_CODE -DMKL_ILP64 -DMKL_INT=long \
-std=c++14 -mavx2 -Wvla -Wall -Wno-write-strings -Wno-parentheses \
-Wno-uninitialized -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-strict-overflow \
-fno-tree-sink -fno-math-errno -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-but-set-variable \
-Wno-unused-function -Waggressive-loop-optimizations -Wno-misleading-indentation \
-DBUILDING_IN_OPCLIBS_DIR -DTURBO_CMP_EXTRACTION -DSECURE -DTCL84 -DUSE_LVBASE \
-D__EXTENSIONS__ -DCONST86="" -D__STRICT_ANSI__ -DUSE_OLD_CANVAS -DUSE_OLD_IMAGE \
-DUSE_NON_CONST -DHAVE_COIN_LIBS -fopt-info-vec-optimized -Wno-unknown-pragmas \
-fno-strict-aliasing patterngenerator.cc -o pattern
```

Comment: Generic Makefile cleanup suggestions: Put Warnings in one variable (`WARNINGS:=-Wall -Wextra ...`), definitions in another (`DEFINITIONS:=-D_SYSTYPE_SYSV ...`), switches in another (`SWITCHES:=-fopt-info-vec-optimized ...`). Then use `$(CXX)` for the compiler instead of hardcoding its path into the Makefile, and add `$(WARNINGS) $(DEFINITIONS) $(SWITCHES)` to the rule. Use `-o $@` instead of `-o pattern`, and `$<` instead of `patterngenerator.cc` in the rule. You are now looking at a much more easily read, maintained, and modifyable Makefile. There is more you could do, but it's a start.